# Docker Build throws a file not found error when the file is there

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile, devops, dockerhub

Everytime I attempt to copy `Brevity.Api.xml`, it'll always end up with a 'Not found' issue and would cause build failures. Listing the files in the directory of the where the docker build is at before executing the copying instructions show that the file is indeed there. What am I missing? Check **step 11** (At the bottom of the log) in the build log

```
Pulling cache layers for index.docker.io/Brevitydata/Brevity-api:0.4.43...
Done!
KernelVersion: 4.4.0-1060-aws
Components: [{u'Version': u'18.03.1-ee-3', u'Name': u'Engine', u'Details': {u'KernelVersion': u'4.4.0-1060-aws', u'Os': u'linux', u'BuildTime': u'2018-08-30T18:42:30.000000000+00:00', u'ApiVersion': u'1.37', u'MinAPIVersion': u'1.12', u'GitCommit': u'b9a5c95', u'Arch': u'amd64', u'Experimental': u'false', u'GoVersion': u'go1.10.2'}}]
Arch: amd64
BuildTime: 2018-08-30T18:42:30.000000000+00:00
ApiVersion: 1.37
Platform: {u'Name': u''}
Version: 18.03.1-ee-3
MinAPIVersion: 1.12
GitCommit: b9a5c95
Os: linux
GoVersion: go1.10.2
Starting build of index.docker.io/Brevitydata/Brevity-api:0.4.49...
Step 1/12 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
---> 1742a2119970
Step 2/12 : WORKDIR /app
Removing intermediate container 887fcd1e995e
---> bac77da95fad
Step 3/12 : COPY . .
---> 009da497612e
Step 4/12 : RUN dotnet restore Brevity.Api/Brevity.Api.csproj
---> Running in 5ba2d2896e6d
Restore completed in 40.71 sec for /app/Brevity.Repo/Brevity.Repo.csproj.
Restore completed in 552.05 ms for /app/Brevity.Repo.BCL/Brevity.Repo.BCL.csproj.
Restore completed in 7.57 sec for /app/Brevity.Repo.Auth/Brevity.Repo.Auth.csproj.
Restore completed in 743.11 ms for /app/Brevity.Infra.Service/Brevity.Infra.Service.csproj.
Restore completed in 712.74 ms for /app/Brevity.Infra.Preprocessing/Brevity.Infra.Preprocessing.csproj.
Restore completed in 611.66 ms for /app/Brevity.Infra.Auth/Brevity.Infra.Auth.csproj.
Restore completed in 2.25 sec for /app/Brevity.Infra.Api.Limiter/Brevity.Infra.Api.Limiter.csproj.
Restore completed in 432.34 ms for /app/Brevity.Base.Domain/Brevity.Base.Domain.csproj.
Restore completed in 416.64 ms for /app/Brevity.Base.BCL/Brevity.Base.BCL.csproj.
Restore completed in 423.75 ms for /app/Brevity.Base.Auth/Brevity.Base.Auth.csproj.
Restore completed in 1.56 sec for /app/Brevity.Api/Brevity.Api.csproj.
Removing intermediate container 5ba2d2896e6d
---> 23c6d213de70
Step 5/12 : COPY . ./
---> 6f89563fb030
Step 6/12 : RUN dotnet publish Brevity.Api/Brevity.Api.csproj -c Release -o out
---> Running in d78bf8192d4e
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.5.0+d4cbfca49 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Restore completed in 240.18 ms for /app/Brevity.Repo/Brevity.Repo.csproj.
Restore completed in 2.13 ms for /app/Brevity.Repo.BCL/Brevity.Repo.BCL.csproj.
Restore completed in 35.24 ms for /app/Brevity.Repo.Auth/Brevity.Repo.Auth.csproj.
Restore completed in 3.16 ms for /app/Brevity.Infra.Service/Brevity.Infra.Service.csproj.
Restore completed in 14.94 ms for /app/Brevity.Infra.Preprocessing/Brevity.Infra.Preprocessing.csproj.
Restore completed in 11.43 ms for /app/Brevity.Infra.Auth/Brevity.Infra.Auth.csproj.
Restore completed in 31.84 ms for /app/Brevity.Infra.Api.Limiter/Brevity.Infra.Api.Limiter.csproj.
Restore completed in 1.64 ms for /app/Brevity.Base.Domain/Brevity.Base.Domain.csproj.
Restore completed in 1.58 ms for /app/Brevity.Base.BCL/Brevity.Base.BCL.csproj.
Restore completed in 1.9 ms for /app/Brevity.Base.Auth/Brevity.Base.Auth.csproj.
Restore completed in 3.69 ms for /app/Brevity.Api/Brevity.Api.csproj.
Brevity.Base.BCL -> /app/Brevity.Base.BCL/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/Brevity.Base.BCL.dll
Brevity.Base.Auth -> /app/Brevity.Base.Auth/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/Brevity.Base.Auth.dll
ViewModels/WebsocketCommand/WebsocketCommandViewModel.cs(15,13): warning CS0612: 'WebsocketCommandViewModel.Id' is obsolete [/app/Brevity.Base.Domain/Brevity.Base.Domain.csproj]
ViewModels/WebsocketCommand/UpdateWebsocketCommandInputModel.cs(20,30): warning CS0612: 'WebsocketCommandViewModel.Id' is obsolete [/app/Brevity.Base.Domain/Brevity.Base.Domain.csproj]
ViewModels/WebsocketCommand/UpdateWebsocketCommandInputModel.cs(25,34): warning CS0612: 'WebsocketCommandViewModel.Id' is obsolete [/app/Brevity.Base.Domain/Brevity.Base.Domain.csproj]
Brevity.Base.Domain -> /app/Brevity.Base.Domain/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/Brevity.Base.Domain.dll
Created package at /app/Brevity.Base.Domain/bin/Release/Brevity.Data.1.0.0.nupkg.
Brevity.Repo.BCL -> /app/Brevity.Repo.BCL/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/Brevity.Repo.BCL.dll
Brevity.Repo.Auth -> /app/Brevity.Repo.Auth/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/Brevity.Repo.Auth.dll
Brevity.Repo -> /app/Brevity.Repo/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/Brevity.Repo.dll
Brevity.Infra.Preprocessing -> /app/Brevity.Infra.Preprocessing/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/Brevity.Infra.Preprocessing.dll
Brevity.Api -> /app/Brevity.Api/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/Brevity.Api.dll
Brevity.Api -> /app/out/
Removing intermediate container d78bf8192d4e
---> fc7bab01292f
Step 7/12 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
---> 49a8777ecaba
Step 8/12 : WORKDIR /app
---> Using cache
---> b5e9eed15764
Step 9/12 : COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
---> 6627192f71e4
Step 10/12 : RUN ls
---> Running in 1434f9853080
FluentValidation.AspNetCore.dll
FluentValidation.DependencyInjectionExtensions.dll
FluentValidation.dll
IdentityModel.dll
IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity.dll
IdentityServer4.Storage.dll
IdentityServer4.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.dll
Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll
Microsoft.Bcl.HashCode.dll
Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions.dll
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.dll
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll
Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.dll
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.dll
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.dll
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.dll
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.dll
Microsoft.OpenApi.dll
NCalc.dll
Newtonsoft.Json.Bson.dll
Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Brevity.Api
Brevity.Api.deps.json
Brevity.Api.dll
Brevity.Api.pdb
Brevity.Api.runtimeconfig.json
Brevity.Api.xml
Brevity.Base.Auth.dll
Brevity.Base.Auth.pdb
Brevity.Base.BCL.dll
Brevity.Base.BCL.pdb
Brevity.Base.Domain.dll
Brevity.Base.Domain.pdb
Brevity.Infra.Api.Limiter.dll
Brevity.Infra.Api.Limiter.pdb
Brevity.Infra.Auth.dll
Brevity.Infra.Auth.pdb
Brevity.Infra.Preprocessing.dll
Brevity.Infra.Preprocessing.pdb
Brevity.Infra.Service.dll
Brevity.Infra.Service.pdb
Brevity.Repo.Auth.dll
Brevity.Repo.Auth.pdb
Brevity.Repo.BCL.dll
Brevity.Repo.BCL.pdb
Brevity.Repo.dll
Brevity.Repo.pdb
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.dll
Npgsql.dll
Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial.dll
Polly.dll
Scrutor.dll
SendGrid.dll
Serilog.AspNetCore.dll
Serilog.Extensions.Hosting.dll
Serilog.Extensions.Logging.dll
Serilog.Formatting.Compact.dll
Serilog.Settings.Configuration.dll
Serilog.Sinks.Console.dll
Serilog.Sinks.Debug.dll
Serilog.Sinks.File.dll
Serilog.dll
StackExchange.Redis.dll
Stripe.net.dll
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations.dll
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters.dll
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.dll
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.dll
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.dll
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.dll
System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.dll
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll
System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.dll
VaultSharp.dll
appsettings.Development.json
appsettings.json
runtimes
web.config
Removing intermediate container 1434f9853080
---> de41029bd7bf
Step 11/12 : COPY Brevity.pfx Brevity.Api.xml .
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder345555611/Brevity.Api.xml: no such file or directory
```

- There are no additional docker configurations like `.dockerignore`.
- All builds are done on Docker hub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is already present in the container then why you are trying to COPY it again?

`COPY` command is used to copy files from Host to Image.

Comment: This entire project does not contain a .dockerignore file. Even if I think it doesn't I just checked, no file of that sort :(

Comment: @Nicholas, When you run `ls` on step 10. It is running inside the container not on the host system. Can you please do the `ls` on your system where you are running the `docker build`.

Comment: Apologies, may you advice exactly where I should put the ```ls```? My docker builds are done on Docker hub.

Comment: If the file is already present in the container then why you are trying to COPY it again?

Comment: hmm.. mind updating your answer? Think u got it right.

Comment: Edited the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

`COPY` doesn't copy the files within the image. It copies files from HOST to IMAGE.

When you did `RUN ls`, you are within the image where the file is present and your current working directory is `/app` within the image. So that means, the `/app` directory inside the image contains your .xml `file`.

Now if you want to copy it somewhere else within the image, you need to `RUN` `copy` command within the image.

So, change the command 11 as below.

```
RUN copy Brevity.pfx "destination directory within the image"
RUN copy Brevity.Api.xml "destination directory within the image"
```